# Can't change value in json

Tags: php, json

I have a .json file with player name, mail address, field name and score on that field. Like this:

```
{"0":{"name":"test","password":"test","mail":"test@test.test","test3":0,"test2":0},"1":{"...
```

I want to change the score at one field, but I can't. I tried this way:

```
        $jsonn = file_get_contents('data/userdata.json');
        $arrayy = json_decode($jsonn, true);
        $field = $_SESSION['fieldname'];

        $arrayy[$felhasznev][$palya] = $pontszam;
```

And I also tried this but not helped:

```
        $jsonn = file_get_contents('data/userdata.json');
        $arrayy = json_decode($jsonn, true);
        $field = $_SESSION['fieldname'];
        foreach ($arrayy as $key => $valuee){
            if($valuee['name'] == $username){
                $valuee[$field] = $score;
            }
        }
```

I'm beginner in JSON so maybe something trivial...

Comment: In the first example, none of the following 3 variables are defined: `$felhasznev`, `$palya`, `$pontszam`. Is there more code you aren't showing here?

Comment: In the second example, you'll need a `&` before the `$valuee` if you want to change the value of an array element while iterating.

Comment: `print_r($arrayy);` should help with the structure.

Comment: Yes, my code is very long, that's just the essence. Every variables are defined, and works good, just to change in json is the problem..

Comment: where to be that & ? which $valuee ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) parse json file to objects, you're using associative array, to have an associative array you have to pass a second argument as true, like:

```
<?php

$file = file_get_contents("file.json");

$players = json_decode($file, true);

$err = json_last_error();

if ($err != JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
    print_r($err);
    die("Error in json file :/");
}

var_dump($players);

foreach ($players as $key => $val) {
    if ($players[$key]["name"] == "test") {
        $players[$key]["test3"] = $players[$key]["test3"] + 1;
        $players[$key]["test2"] = $players[$key]["test2"] + 1;
    }
}

var_dump($players);

file_put_contents("new_file.json", json_encode($players));
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) In your sample json, there is value (0) not enclosed in double quote (parsing error!).

(2) the first code should work if json is ok.

(3) in the second code, you skipped the "id" identifier (if json is ok).

Comment: verify json (print_r($arrayy);) to check if it was parsed correctly?